# iOS simulator is not launching

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

I am facing this problem again and again. Anybody can give the solution to this problem except reboot the Mac?

I have already tried these tricks

1. **simulator-->services-->a reset content and settings**,
   closing xcode and re-opening
   **xcode --> developer toos --> simulator -->(open the simulator)**,
   quit simulator
   **Activity monitor -->**(the simulator is closed so nothing here to force close)
2. 

First of all quit your simulator.
And then quit and restart Xcode.
And then run your project.

3. Restart xcode and the simulator

Comment: whats your xcode version?

Comment: Did you try on differents projects ?

Comment: Xcode 6.1 and Yes I've used on other project

Comment: Explain what is happening.  What errors are you seeing?  What dialog boxes?  What do you see in syslog?  Are you renaming Xcode.app? (don't).

Comment: I was using the Xcode 6.3. Now it's working in Xcode 7.1. No problem at all.

Answer (score 118):

I also have this issue and googled this, which redirect to this question. Mine was `xcode10` What i have done is as follows

1. Quit the simulator & Xcode.
2. Opened `Activity monitor`, selected `cpu` option and search for `sim`, killing all the process shown as result.
3. Then fired up the terminal and run `sudo xcrun simctl erase all`. It will delete all content of all simulators. By content if you logged in somewhere password will be gone, all developer apps installed in that simulator will be gone.

Doing these resolved my issue.

Comment: I've had the same problem when both Xcode 10 and 9 were installed. The error message was: "Device iPhone XS Max is available but has no defaultDisplay". Thanks for the solution!

Comment: For me it worked even without step 3. It helped just to remove all the `launcd_sim` processes (I had several), all the dependent ones removed automatically. Thanks for an answer!

Comment: Shutting down and restarting after step 2 helps. Sometimes the sim processes don't quit and this will ensure that they do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. This fixed the problem.

I have 2 Xcode versions installed so maybe it was causing some issues with the Simulator runtime. I guess removing the data and processes fixes the issue.

Comment: This works for me too, though after stressing myself by unistalling and re-downloading xcode

Comment: Worked for me after a restart, but not sure if it was these steps or the restart that solved it :)

Answer (score 48):

Under `Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme`, check these settings once.

Right now it is showing `None`. That is NOT what you want.
Choose the Executable from the dropdown. It should have something like: `<app_name>.app`.

[image: Edit scheme window screenshot]

Comment: To find the Run Window go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme

Comment: your screenshot does not explain nothing. very poor answer. you need to tell people what to do there, namely SELECT EXECUTABLE, because you have None right now that is why Simulator does not start.

Comment: well I had more serious problem as my simulator just crashes at start since I had two versions of Xcode installed. Tried restart my laptop before without help. Today I just tried the solution here, by just checking at the Edit Scheme once without changing anything, then restarted my laptop again, now both Xcode versions simulators work. Maybe a coincidence, but I'll give you credit here :)

Comment: Under Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme, check the Launch option, it should be selected Automatically

Answer (score 16):

None of the above solutions helped me.

I also tried

```
sudo killall -10 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

And even after clean Xcode reinstallation my simulators continue closing after launching.

So i removed all simulators from **Window - Device & Organizers**
[image: Remove all simulators]

And then added new one's

[image: Add new simulators]

And the problem has gone

Answer (score 5):

In my case `tmp` directory was not there for some reason, creating it giving adequate permissions saved my day.

```
sudo mkdir /private/tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /private/tmp
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48075384/6919038

Comment: thanks for the answer this help me a lot

Answer (score 2):

In my case, was just kill the process: `sudo killall -10 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService`

Answer (score 0):

Enable/change location in the xcode console. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following solved my issue

1. Open edit scheme

[image: Open edit scheme]

2. Check that lunch is automatically

[image: Check that lunch is automatically]

Answer (score 0):

I was having this behavior in xcode 14.2, visual studio 17.5 preview 6.  The folders previous posts refer to are not there to delete.  In my case, I finally discovered that after rebuilding certs due to the main apple cert expiration on Feb 6, 2023, the project had chosen the distribution cert for use in simulator.  I had to remove the account, re-add it, and then the developer cert would show, but it would de-select itself oddly enough.  I finally set it, closed the properties, and it stuck... after which the simulator came right up.  Hopefully that saves someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all methods above and still had the same error.
Since its the simulator causing a mess , i just created a new project on Xcode and just chose new device and when device was powered on i launched my expo project and it worked

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to open XCode and make sure the iOS version was installed. After opening XCode, from the top bar open the simulators dropdown and if you don't see a list of devices, select "install iOS version xx". After downloading the devices, close the simulator and reopen.

Answer (score 0):

I just rebooted my Mac and the problem was resolved. Not elegant, but easy.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all steps above and nothing worked for me, so i opened xcode, and started a new project, then selected App. Once i did that, xcode installed all missing parts. In my case, was that the iOS was not properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me.

Go to **System settings** > **Storage settings**. Click Developer, From the list delete Xcode Cache.

Worked for me

Answer (score -1):

In Xcode select **`Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run > Options`** tab.

Confirm  **`Launch due to a background fetch event`** is ***not selected***.

See the image below ...

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Long shot but in my case I just moved my `Xcode` to `Applications` and restarted `Xcode`.