# Error Running React Native App From Terminal (iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, ios-simulator

I am following the tutorial on the official React Native website.

Using the following to build my project:

```
react-native run-ios
```

I get the error:

```
Found Xcode project TestProject.xcodeproj
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer   
tool or in PATH

Command failed: xcrun instruments -s
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer 
tool or in PATH
```

Although, when I run the app from the .xcodeproj, everything works fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 995, accepted):

Check out this link ([Running react-native run-ios occurs an error?](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7965)). It appears to be a problem with the location of `Command line tools`.

In Xcode, select Xcode menu, then Preferences, then Locations tab. Select your Xcode version from the dropdown and exit Xcode.

[image: XCode location tab]

Comment: So I had done that and for some reason installing homebrew disabled it. I had to select it again from xcode _after_ installing homebrew.

Comment: Still have the error even with a CLT selected... :/

Answer (score 154):

You may need to install or set the location of the **Xcode Command Line Tools**.

## Via command line

If you have Xcode downloaded you can run the following to set the path:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
```

If the command line tools haven't been installed yet, you may need to run this first:

```
xcode-select --install
```

You may need to accept the Xcode license before installing command line tools:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

---

## Via Xcode

Or adjust the `Command Line Tools` setting via Xcode (`Xcode > Preferences > Locations`):

[image: Xcode preferences - Locations tab]

Answer (score 36):

An update for anybody (like me) who's run into this in Xcode 13 -- the `instruments` command has been removed.

Updating to the latest version of `react-native` in your `package.json` file will no longer try to use the `instruments` command.

Comment: For me, upgrading to react-native 0.64.0 was enough (from 0.63.2)

Comment: seems to still run OK for me by launching via xcode, just the cli start has issues

Answer (score 21):

By default, after installing **Xcode** command-line not selected, so open **Xcode** and go to **Preferences >> Locations** and set **Command Line Tools**...

This worked for me in **MAC High Sierra**, **Xcode Version 9.3**:

[image: Xcode Preferences]

Press `i` to open **iOS emulator**...

[image: Press a to open Android device or emulator, or i to open iOS emulator.]

And You can see a cool new iPhone simulator like below image:

[image: React Native prints, I'm Alireza Dezfoolian, a Front End Developer!]

Answer (score 14):

In my case the problem was that Xcode was not installed.

Comment: the react native official website clearly states that you need Xcode in order for react native to work.

Answer (score 12):

I had to accept the XCode license after my first install before I could run it. You can run the following to get the license prompt via command line. You have to type `agree` and confirm as well.

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Comment: You can also accept the license immediately, if you want to: `sudo xcodebuild -license accept` (source: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/213151/89456)

Answer (score 8):

Problem is your Xcode version is not set on Command Line Tools, to solve this problem open Xcode>Menu>preferences> location> here for Command Line tools select your Xcode version, that's it. [image]

Answer (score 5):

For those like me who come to this page with this problem after updating Xcode but don't have an issue with the location setting, restarting my computer did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it turns out that there was an iOS system update pending asking to restart the computer. Restart and let the update finish solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the SDKROOT environment variable was wrong, which referred to an old version of iPhoneOSxx.x.sdk. (Perhaps this would have automatically resolved itself after a reboot?)

You can check by running `echo $SDKROOT` and verifying that it's a valid path.

I fixed it by updating in .bash_profile:

```
export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these solutions worked for me. These two similar problems offer temporary solutions that worked, it  seems the simulator process isn't being shutdown correctly:

**Killing Simulator Processes**

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/52533391/11279823

1. Quit the simulator & Xcode.
2. Opened `Activity monitor`, selected `cpu` option and search for `sim`, killing all the process shown as result.
3. Then fired up the terminal and run `sudo xcrun simctl erase all`. It will delete all content of all simulators. By content if you logged in somewhere password will be gone, all developer apps installed in that simulator will be gone.

**Opening Simulator before starting the package**

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/55374768/11279823

`open -a Simulator; npm start`

Hopefully a permanent solution is found.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Xcode Preferences
2. Locate the location tab
3. Set the Xcode version in Given Command Line Tools

Now, it ll successfully work.

Answer (score 2):

If the previous answers didn't help you, you're probably dealing with an outdated `react-native` version. If you want to run your app on device without upgrading React-Native, you'll have to run the app directly from Xcode instead of doing it in the CLI. So open the `<appname>.xcworkspace`, select your device on the right-hand dropdown and press the "Run" icon.

[Xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcwkl.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Mac: After all, you are getting this issue, there may be a chance of missing the following in **System Preferences** -> **Network** -> **Ethernet** -> Select **Advanced** -> **Proxies**

add the following line,

*.local,localhost

Answer (score 0):

simply go to Xcode

click on Xcode from the top left menu
**Xcode->preferences-> location->** click comman line option and set **Xcode version**.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I got the solution,

```
> rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
> sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
> xcode-select --install
> sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

Xcode > Preferences > Location > Command Line Tools choose.

Answer (score -3):

For any such problem:

1. Go to `.expo` folder
2. Find `apk-cache`
3. Remove that folder

and you are done..

Hope it helps?