# Can't run my react-native project with new version of iphone simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios11

Since a recent update, I get an error when I try to run my React Native project through command lines:

```
Found Xcode project MyProject.xcodeproj
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH
Command failed: xcrun instruments -s
```

Seems like the `iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk` is not available anymore and has been replaced by `iPhoneSimulator11.1.sdk`.

I tried to follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778607/error-running-react-native-app-from-terminal-ios) with both the CLI and Xcode options to fix the xcrun error but it didn't fix my issue.

Is there a way to say to react native to switch to the new simulator? Isn't it suppose to update automatically?

Comment: rebooting did it

Comment: Confirmed. I didn't reboot after upgrading to xcode 10.2. Doing so fixed the iPhoneSimulator version.