# Error running React Native app From Terminal(IOS)

Tags: react-native

I am following the tutorial on the official React Native website.
Using the following to build my project:

```
react-native run-ios
```

I got the error:

```
Found Xcode workspace AwesomeProjectMobile.xcworkspace
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH

Command failed: xcrun instruments -s
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Running React Native App From Terminal (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778607/error-running-react-native-app-from-terminal-ios)