# Error running react-native application without expo

Tags: react-native

When starting the react native application, it gives an error. But when running through expo , there are no errors.

node v14.18.0
npm 8.1.2

Error:

```
react-native run-ios
(node:96928) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
info Found Xcode project tinderReact.xcodeproj
xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk macosx -find instruments 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 17664: (null) (errno=No such file or directory)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH
error Command failed: xcrun instruments -s
xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk macosx -find instruments 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 17664: (null) (errno=No such file or directory)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH
. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

UPD:Updated macos to latest and xcode to latest. There are now new errors

```
    info Found Xcode project tinderReact.xcodeproj
2022-03-18 11:13:45.082 xcodebuild[9769:197239] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-03-18 11:13:45.083 xcodebuild[9769:197239] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find instruments 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 17664: (null) (errno=No such file or directory)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH
error Command failed: xcrun instruments -s
2022-03-18 11:13:45.082 xcodebuild[9769:197239] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-03-18 11:13:45.083 xcodebuild[9769:197239] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find instruments 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 17664: (null) (errno=No such file or directory)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH
. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Comment: It appears to be a problem with the location of Command line tools. Have a look at this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39779171/9720524

Comment: This path is correct. Again, everything works correctly through the expo.https://imgur.com/a/GAFEiom