# xcode 9 simulator error unable to boot the simulator launchd failed to respond mac os sierra

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

xcode 9  simulator error unable to boot the simulator launchd failed to respond mac os sierra

I ave tried deleting contents from derived data, restarting Xcode , Uninstall and install of xcode etc.

Answer (score 54):

In this case, `launchd` is crashing when trying to launch.

This could be as a result of deleting the `/private/tmp` folder.

To resolve this, I typed the following commands on my terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /private/tmp 
sudo chmod 1777 /private/tmp
```

Comment: Thank You so much, man !! The only solution that worked for me.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Xcode 11, but this solution did not fix it for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: @aksh1t Deleting and adding the Simulator back and then restarting the computer fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Removing said folder, recreating it and setting permission to 777 worked.

Comment: For me, with Xcode 10.3 as well as 11.1, /private/tmp was already present, so just setting chmod 1777 worked.

Comment: I'm using xcode 9.2. I had the same problem. For me the tmp folder was already there. Removing and creating the folder with the given permissions solved the issue.

Comment: sudo chmod 777 /private/tmp worked for me, not 1777

Comment: Surprisingly, this fixed my issue too. 

`sudo rm -fr /private/tmp/*`
then 
`sudo chmod ugo+wrx /private/tmp`

Answer (score 2):

I observed these issues sometimes when my mac is not connected to the internet. So here is a solutions list one of them may solve your problem.

1. Check if you have an internet connection running in your mac.
2. Restart the simulator.
3. Restart mac if required.

Hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: It worked thanks.
Although i don't need to restart my mac. Just check the internet connection at your system.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Mac solved it for me.