# Xcode: Simulator doesn't start after adding library

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Xcode 10.3, Swift 5

I started a new project, built and ran it once (it worked), then added the "Swift-SMTP" library (using the Swift Package Manager) according to the installation [guide](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-SMTP#installation).

This created new options for the simulator: There's now 2 per device (e.g. "iPhone SE 12.0" and "iPhone SE 12.4").

Additionally, while a build is successful, the simulator won't start - no matter what device I pick.

What I already tried:

- Cleaned the build folder (Product - Clean Build Folder)
- Built it multiple times (Product - Build)
- Restarted Xcode
- Restarted the Mac
- Killed the "simulator" processes (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52533391/2016165))

Nothing worked! I deleted the project and started another one, which came to the same result.

I noticed that "Executable" says "None" (Product - Scheme - Edit Scheme - Run - Info) and there are only two other options: "Ask on Launch" and "Other...".

The simulator works fine with other projects (that use CocoaPods), it just doesn't with this one. How do I fix this?

Comment: So I presume this is you: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-SMTP/issues/102

Comment: @matt I opened a bug report on Github too, yes but not sure if the author is still offering support. If he does, I'll link to it here but please delete the link in the meantime, as it doesn't add anything to the question. It's weird that a library would manage to break the simulator. Have you got any suggestions what I could try to fix it?