# Xcode - "Could not launch <AppName>”, No such file or directory Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode12

- Xcode12.0 (12A7209)
- iOS 14 or 13

I can build the project and install to iPhone, but when I try to debug it, Xcode Could not launch the app.

The error message is

> Could not launch “”
> No such file or directory (/Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-joaojfh9ejapjxmapjrxmpaxjmp/Build/Products//.app/)

I thought the file is not exists, but it exists.

```
$ ll /Users/<UserName>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<AppName>-joaojfh9ejapjxmapjrxmpaxjmp/Build/Products/<scheme-name>/<AppName>.app/<AppName>
-rwxr-xr-x  1 <UserName>  staff  26435520  9 23 09:36 /Users/<UserName>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<AppName>-joaojfh9ejapjxmapjrxmpaxjmp/Build/Products/<scheme-name>/<AppName>.app/<AppName>
```

So I don't know how to solve this problem.

This error occurs with only Xcode12, not found with Xcode11.

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of possibilities why this happens, you can go thru the solutions provided in a similar thread here: [iOS simulator is not launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296360/ios-simulator-is-not-launching)